# How to define a function that takes a weight and outputs a price

Tags: python

I want to add a def function that takes in weight and outputs cost but I don't know how to make that work with the if elif loop

```
weight = float(input("Enter package weight: ")) #package weight
cost_ground_premium = 125.00 #flat charge for premium
if weight <= 2: #package weighs 2 lb or less
  cost_ground = weight * 1.50 + 20 # $1.50/lb, flat charge of $20
elif weight <= 6: #over 2lb but less/equal to 6lb
  cost_ground = weight * 3.00 + 20 # $3/lb + flat charge
elif weight <= 10: #over 6lb but less/equal to 10lb
  cost_ground = weight * 4.00 + 20 # $4/lb + flat charge
else: #over 10lb
  cost_ground = weight * 4.75 + 20 # $4.75/lb + flat charge
print("Ground Shipping $", round(cost_ground, 2))
print("Ground Shipping Premium $", round(cost_ground_premium, 2))
drone_weight = float(input("Enter package weight if using Drone Shipping: "))
if drone_weight <= 2: # $4.50/lb. No flat charge
  cost_drone = drone_weight * 4.50 #no flat charge
elif drone_weight <= 6: # $9/lb 
  cost_drone = drone_weight * 9.00
elif drone_weight <= 10: # $12/lb
  cost_drone = drone_weight * 12.00
else: # $14.25/lb
  cost_drone = drone_weight * 14.25
print("Drone Shipping $", round(cost_drone, 2))
```

Comment: Hello Chris! Is your question how to define a function? It's a little unclear from your wording. I'd also encourage you to break out your 'loop' question into a separate question, as we try to keep questions to a single question-and-response (makes it easier for others to search for solutions).

Comment: I want to modify the code by adding a def function that will take in the weight then output cost after the calculation. I just don’t know how to do that the right way

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole logic inside a def, except the input

```
def calculateCost():
```

Initialise
weight=1
Then just use a while loop.

```
while weight!=0:
  weight = float(input("Enter package weight: "))
  calculateCost(weight)
```

Also make sure in the function if weight is 0 it just pass.

Comment: I think your `while` loop needs a bit more fleshing out... as it stands it both won't compile, and won't ever exit.

Comment: Ah yes, realised that and updated

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrale cost_ground and cost_drone out of if and elif blocks.
Below I write function and cycle for your code.

```py
def func(weight, drone_weight):

    cost_ground = None
    cost_drone = None
    cost_ground_premium = 125.00 #flat charge for premium

    if weight <= 2: #package weighs 2 lb or less
        cost_ground = weight * 1.50 + 20 # $1.50/lb, flat charge of $20
    elif weight <= 6: #over 2lb but less/equal to 6lb
        cost_ground = weight * 3.00 + 20 # $3/lb + flat charge
    elif weight <= 10: #over 6lb but less/equal to 10lb
        cost_ground = weight * 4.00 + 20 # $4/lb + flat charge
    else: #over 10lb
        cost_ground = weight * 4.75 + 20 # $4.75/lb + flat charge


    if drone_weight <= 2: # $4.50/lb. No flat charge
        cost_drone = drone_weight * 4.50 #no flat charge
    elif drone_weight <= 6: # $9/lb 
        cost_drone = drone_weight * 9.00
    elif drone_weight <= 10: # $12/lb
        cost_drone = drone_weight * 12.00
    else: # $14.25/lb
        cost_drone = drone_weight * 14.25


    return (round(cost_ground, 2), round(cost_drone, 2), cost_ground_premium)


while 1:
    weight = float(input("Enter package weight: ")) #package weight
    if weight == 0:
        break
    
    drone_weight = float(input("Enter package weight if using Drone Shipping: "))

    cost_ground, cost_drone, cost_ground_premium = func(weight, drone_weight)

    print("Ground Shipping $", cost_ground)
    print("Ground Shipping Premium $", cost_ground_premium)
    print("Drone Shipping $", cost_drone)
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. What if I wanted weight = 0 to exit the program. How would I go about that?

Comment: @ChrisD You can use break to exit from cycle

Answer (score 0):

```
weight = float(input("Enter package weight: ")) #package weight
cost_ground_premium = 125.00 #flat charge for premium

def get_cost_ground(weight, flat_charge=20, is_premimum=False):
  # flat charge for premium
  if is_premimum:
    return cost_ground_premium
  
  if weight <= 2: #package weighs 2 lb or less
    cost_ground = weight * 1.50 + flat_charge # $1.50/lb, flat charge of $20
  elif weight <= 6: #over 2lb but less/equal to 6lb
    cost_ground = weight * 3.00 + flat_charge # $3/lb + flat charge
  elif weight <= 10: #over 6lb but less/equal to 10lb
    cost_ground = weight * 4.00 + flat_charge # $4/lb + flat charge
  else: #over 10lb
    cost_ground = weight * 4.75 + flat_charge # $4.75/lb + flat charge
  return cost_ground
```

Then call using `get_cost_ground(weight)`. For premium call method `get_cost_ground(weight,is_premimum=True)`.
Similarly you can do for Drone Shipping calculation

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This is the (simple) approach I would take, if there's something you want clarified please let me know :)

```py
SHIPPING_PRICE_DECIMALS = 2

def calculate_ground_shipping_price(weight: float):
    FLAT_CHARGE = 20

    cost = None

    if weight <= 2:
        cost = weight * 1.5
    elif weight <= 6:
        cost = weight * 3
    elif weight <= 10:
        cost = weight * 4
    else:
        cost = weight * 4.75

    return round(cost + FLAT_CHARGE, SHIPPING_PRICE_DECIMALS)


def calculate_drone_shipping_price(weight):
    cost = None

    if weight <= 2:
        cost = weight * 4.5
    elif weight <= 6:
        cost = weight * 9
    elif weight <= 10:
        cost = weight * 12
    else:
        cost = weight * 14.25

    return round(cost, SHIPPING_PRICE_DECIMALS)


weight = 8

ground_shipping_price = calculate_ground_shipping_price(weight)
print(f"ground_shipping_price = {ground_shipping_price}")

drone_shipping_price = calculate_drone_shipping_price(weight)
print(f"drone_shipping_price = {drone_shipping_price}")
```

If you want both prices to be returned from the same method you can return a tuple like `return (ground_price, drone_price)` and unpack it like `ground_price, second_price = calculate_shipping_price(weight)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a function like this:

```
def calculate_cost(weight: float, costs: dict, flat_fee: float) -> float:
```

The arguments of this function are the weight - which you will get by input elsewhere - flat_fee, which is the flat fee being applied and a costs table, which we'll define as a dict.

Then your calculate function should iterate through the costs table until it finds a valid weight threshold.

```
# This is a dict of the costs. The first element is the cost to ship anything greater than the weight of the last key. Keys are the 'weight' and the value is the 'price per pound'.
costs_ground = {
  0: 4.75,  # This is your 'greater than the rest of the cost structure cost'
  2: 1.50,
  6: 3.00,
  10: 4.0,
}

costs_drone = {
  0: 14.25,
  2: 4.50,
  6: 9.00,
  10: 12.00,
}


def calculate_cost(weight: float, costs: dict, flat_fee: float = 0.00) -> float:
    indices = sorted(costs)
    for idx in indices[1:]:  # This skips the first element in the cost structure
        if weight <= costs.get(idx, 0.00):
            return (costs.get(idx) * weight) + flat_fee)
    return (costs.get(0, 0.00) * weight) + flat_fee)

while True:  # Will continue until the program is force-killed
    weight = float(input("Enter package weight: "))
    ground_price = calculate_cost(weight, costs_ground, 20.0)
    drone_price = calculate_cost(weight, costs_drone)
    print(f"Ground Shipping ${}", round(ground_price, 2))
    print(f"Drone Shipping ${}", round(drone_price, 2))
```

There are some edge cases I'm eliding, but this shows you how to abstract the function you're trying to define.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it